# Weird Path in Git directory Structure

Tags: git

I have seen following path in directory of .git.

```
.git/object/3b/12abef878787483abeceddaa5544489abff789a
```

when infact SHA is 3b12abef878787483abeceddaa5544489abff789a

which is the SHA of the contents of the file and hence should be stored without the /.
why did git store the blob in this weird path,what are the advantages of doing so?

Comment: Many file systems either do not support or do not perform well with large numbers of objects in a single directory. I have to imagine this is why git reserves the first two characters of the object sha1 for a subdirectory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is to prevent there being too many files in one directory.  With all the SHA values that start `3b` stored in a sub-directory `3b`, the workload on any single directory is 1/256<sup>th</sup> of what it would be if all the blobs were in a single directory.  Ultimately, this speeds up the performance; there is less searching to do to find a particular blob.

You can see similar effects in the `terminfo` directory, where the entries are sub-divided into directories based on the first letter of the terminal entry. The CPAN system has `authors/id/A/AA/AARDVARK` in its naming hierarchy.

---

> Please elaborate a little bit for me.

Suppose that `git` wants to find the blob `3b12abef878787483abeceddaa5544489abff789a` and the directory partitioning scheme is not in use.  There might be, for sake of argument, 512 blobs, and to get to the file, the kernel might have to read all 512 directory entries in `.git/objects` to find the right entry.

Now suppose that the directory partitioning scheme is in use, and that by a miracle of statistical mischance, there are 256 subdirectories each containing 2 files.  Now the kernel at worst has to read 256 directory entries with 2-byte names in each entry (compared with 512 directory entries with 32-byte names) in the `./git/objects` directory, and then has to read at worst 2 entries with 30-byte names in the `./git/objects/3b` directory.

There are complicating factors, such as imperfectly balanced hashing and memory caching and disk accesses, but the general idea is that distributing the files into multiple subdirectories means that the OS kernel has less work to do to find a file.  If the number of files in a directory will extend into the multiple hundreds, it is worth considering breaking it down.

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit for me I am pretty new to this if you dont mind.

Comment: It's probably also worth adding that git automatically "packs" objects when the total number of "loose objects" gets to what git considers "too high".  That number defaults to 6700 objects, which (if the distribution is perfect) means git runs a lightweight auto-pack when there are more than about 27.2 objects per sub-directory.